# Expanding tick marks and labels beyond data set

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am looking to expand the y- and x-axis values beyond the data for visual reasons. I tried to force the ticks and labels, but it did not work. I wish the two axis to start at zero and end beyond the maximum datapoints. This is my first attempt at `pgfplots.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,backgrounds,arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
%
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        small, 
                        xlabel=Time in min.,
                        ylabel=Distance in mi.,
                        axis y line=left,
                        axis x line=bottom,
                        xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
                        ytick={0,1,1.5,2,...,3.5},
                        xticklabels={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
                        yticklabels={0,1,1.5,2,...,3.5},
                        xtickmin=0,
                        xtickmax=11,
                        ytickmin=0,
                        ytickmax=3.5
                            ] 
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=*] 
                    coordinates {
                        (1,1)
                        (2,1)
                        (5,3)
                        (8,3)
                        (9,2)
                        (10,3)
                                };
                \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visible range of the plot can be specified using `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, etc. If you want to automatically extend the axis ranges beyond the largest values, you can set `enlargelimits=upper` (this behaviour can be controlled quite precisely: You can enlarge the axis by a certain number of units, by a certain percentage, or by a certain length. Check the manual for details).

In your example, you can simply say `xmin=0, ymin=0, enlargelimits=upper`, without the need to specify the ticks yourself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        small, 
                        compat=1.8,
                        xlabel=Time in min.,
                        ylabel=Distance in mi.,
                        axis y line=left,
                        axis x line=bottom,
                        xmin=0,
                        ymin=0,
                        enlargelimits=upper
                            ] 
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=*] 
                    coordinates {
                        (1,1)
                        (2,1)
                        (5,3)
                        (8,3)
                        (9,2)
                        (10,3)
                                };
                \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```